# Simplify a series of IF THEN

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

What I'm trying to do can be explained with this pseudo-code:
if `variable_text1` is either "1", "2", "3" then under the new column called `rating` put "1-3"

Pretty simple but writing it in the "dumb" way is pretty long

```
Table.AddColumn(#"Added cluster_rating", "rating", each if [variable_text1] = "1" then "1-3" else
if [variable_text1] = "2" then "1-3" else
if [variable_text1] = "3" then "1-3" else
null)
```

Problem is when there are a lot of possible textual variable to pick from...is there a smarter way to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to implement in PowerBI as a calculated column:

```
IF [variable_text1] In {"1", "2", "3"}, "1-3"
```

No need to use null, it's a default condition for false outcome.

[Edit]:

If you must use power query, try;

```
if List.Contains({"1","2","3"}, [variable_text1]) then "1-3" else null
```

Comment: I'm building a data model, the requisite is that all the data manipulation is done in "modify query". I did the brute force list of all the possibilities, a function to do what you wrote in Query M would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

How about using this as your custom column?

```
if Number.FromText([variable_text1]) >= 1 and
   Number.FromText([variable_text1]) <= 3
then "1-3"
else null
```

Comment: Can't. variable_text1 is a text variable, it contains values like "7+", "7-" that needs to be grouped.